# how to setup individual kibana dashboards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have elasticsearch running on aws and would like to setup individual dashboards for different customers. Authorization is less of a problem but setting up individual dashboards is a bit of a struggle for me. They should be able to work with the same data but create their own charts. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think Kibana Spaces can help you with this, you can create different Kibana space for each customer for the same Kibana URL and can also share dashboards within these Spaces, you can check the below link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-spaces.html

It's probably a Paid feature and will require Kibana to be 6.7+.
I hope this helps with your query.